# Getting 500 internal server error in Laravel select query

Tags: laravel

I am new to Laravel. I am facing a strange issue. In the controller, there is a select query. After login When I try to searing with that select query I have got 500 internal server errors. But after that when I refresh the page then the result will show. Can anyone please advise me why I am facing this issue?

Comment: Can you provide more info, what error did you see? you can find it in storage/logs folder

Comment: 500 Internal Server Error I have checked the logs there is no 500 internal servers related error. Here are some error there - #48 /home/sevalve1/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(151): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#49 /home/sevalve1/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(116): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#50 /home/sevalve1/public_html/index.php(53): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))

Comment: @Soumyadip it is not a laravel 500 error page? "500 internal server error" can be a million things. if it is a laravel style error page, there is more info in /storage/logs/laravel.log (add the part starting with FATAL ERROR)

Comment: @GertB.Yes I have checked laravel.log file there is below thing showing - #48 /home/sevalve1/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(151): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure)) #49 /home/sevalve1/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(116): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request)) #50 /home/sevalve1/public_html/index.php(53): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))

Comment: @Soumyadip look a little higher in the file... the actual error is in there it starts with the  error, following bij the stack, you posted a part of the stack

Comment: There is no error in the log file. I think select query takes time to fetch data that's why internal server error showing

Comment: @Soumyadip there is an error... since you've posted a part of it... if it takes too much time you don't get a 500 error but a timeout error. If its not a production env you can enable debug in your .env file... that will show the error details in the browser

Comment: Yes, it is production. On .env file debug is already on APP_DEBUG=true